# Replace valuie in text file with php

Tags: php, string, file, text, replace

i have a text file with the following design:

> john smith|1|john@smith.com|nopassword|admin
>   Tom smith|3|tom@smith.com|admin123|user
>   ....

And so on.
Every field is delimited by "|".
What i need to do is replace values for example the password or the account type of a user in this text file.

Tom smith|**5**|tom@smith.com|**admin1234**|**admin**

I succeeded in finding the line and spiting it with explode() but how do i modify the value and write it back on the text file ?

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mydb = file('./DB/users.txt');
foreach($mydb as $line) {
    if(stristr($line,$name)) $pieces = explode("|", $line);
    $position = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[1]);
    $email = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[2]);
    $password = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[3]);
    $atype = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[4]);
```

Comment: Can you put your existing code here?

Comment: Are you trying to modify them all, or a specific one?

Comment: Also, have you considered using a database? This looks more like a job for a database.

Comment: $name     = $_POST['name'];
    $mydb     = file('./DB/users.txt');
    foreach($mydb as $line)
    {
        if(stristr($line,$name))
        $pieces    = explode("|", $line);
        $position  = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[1]);
        $email     = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[2]);
        $password  = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[3]);
        $atype     = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[4]);
    }

Comment: A database it's alright but this is more easy to make the application portable at work.

Comment: I try to modify everyone of them if it's the case but for now password and account type are important.

Comment: FYI, you can **[edit]** your question to add more info instead of using comments. It's kinda difficult to read code in comments. There's an edit link at the bottom left of the question area.

Comment: How many users do you expect to deal with?

Comment: Your code does not match your example data - you're splitting the contents of _single lines_, so why would you then try and replace _line breaks_ in those pieces? _"but how do i modify the value and write it back on the text file ?"_ - you write the replaced values right back into the array elements (`$pieces[x] = str_replace(...);`), implode the array, and then either write it back to the file line-by-line (fopen/write/fclose), or you collect the replaced line strings into a second array, implode that again after the loop with line breaks, and then use file_put_contents to write it in one go.

Comment: not more than between 500 and 1000 not more.

Comment: For 1000 lines you are going to want something more robust than reading and writing files.

Comment: That is the problem i don't know how not to split the file in lines and to find only the particular string i want to change. i figured if i find the line split it and read the value of it but ... staked in finding the line displaying what it contains in rows and ...

Comment: That is the benefit of DBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP gives the options of reading, writing, and appending to files.

You need to open the file, read all content in, and then overwrite the file.  You will get duplicate entries using append.

Here is an example code from https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp:

```
<?php
  $myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  $txt = "John Doe\n";
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  $txt = "Jane Doe\n";
  fwrite($myfile, $txt);
  fclose($myfile);
?>
```

For your code:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $mydb = file('./DB/users.txt'); 

  $output = array();
  foreach($mydb as $line) { 
    if(stristr($line,$name)) {
      $pieces = explode("|", $line); 
      $position = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[1]); 
      $email = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[2]); 
      $password = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[3]); 
      $atype = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r"),"",$pieces[4]); 

      // Glue the variables back together and overwrite $line so that it gets up in the array
      $line = $name & "|" $position & "|" $email & "|" $password & "|" $atype & "\r";
    }
    // put everything in the $output array so that it can be writen to file after this loop
    array_push($output, $line);
  }
  fclose($mydb);

  // Write your output to file
  $mydb = fopen('./DB/users.txt', "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
  foreach($output as $line) { 
    fwrite($mydb, $line);
  }
  fclose($mydb);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways to do this. Here's one way. I commented the code to explain how it works.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];

// use FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES so you won't have to deal with the line breaks
$mydb = file('./DB/users.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

// use a reference (&$line) so the code in your foreach loop modifies the $mydb array
foreach ($mydb as &$line) {
    if (stristr($line,$name)) {

        // assign the elements of the row to variables
        list($name, $number, $email, $password, $type) = explode('|', $line);

        // change whatever you need to change
        $password = 'new password';
        $type = 'new type';

        // overwrite the line with the modified values
        $line = implode('|', [$name, $number, $email, $password, $type]);

        // optional: break out of the loop if you only want to do the replacement
        // for the first item found that matches $_POST['name']
        break;
    }
};

// overwrite the file after the loop
file_put_contents('./DB/users.txt',  implode("\n", $mydb));
```